# Simpliest cross-resolution apps and adaptive UI building. Can't make that in WPF

Tags: wpf, user-interface, resolution

Currently trying to build simpliest cross-resolution app (in other words an adaptive UI). The Apps itself is intended to start at min res:1024x768 and max res: 1920x1080.
However I have no success in doing of that.

[image]
this is 1024x768 window, where everything looks good.

[image]

this is 1920x1080 window, where controls "swam". However pic adapted itself to resolution.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="768" Width="1024"  MinHeight="768" MinWidth="1024" MaxHeight="1080" MaxWidth="1920">

<Grid  ShowGridLines="True">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="80*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="512*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="160*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <GroupBox x:Name="groupBox_Copy" Header="Truck2" Height="148" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="430,503.6,468.6,0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <Button x:Name="button_Copy" Content="Start" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,13,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" RenderTransformOrigin="0.245,-0.667"/>
    </GroupBox>
    <GroupBox x:Name="groupBox_Copy1" Header="Truck3" Height="148" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="752,503.6,146.6,0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <Button x:Name="button_Copy1" Content="Start" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,13,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" RenderTransformOrigin="0.245,-0.667"/>
    </GroupBox>
    <GroupBox x:Name="groupBox_Copy2" Header="Truck1" Height="148" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="148,503.6,750.6,0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Start" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,13,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" RenderTransformOrigin="0.245,-0.667"/>
    </GroupBox>
    <Image x:Name="image"  Grid.Row="1"  Source="Resources/truck.png"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: add Grid.ColumnDefintions and place each GroupBox in a separate column. layout via fixed `Margin`s in not adaptive (as you can see already)

Comment: alternative consider using `UniformGrid`

Comment: Where I have to add a grid. To lower  Row of the main grid?

Comment: yes, of course.

Comment: You won't believe me, however,  I've tried that already. There was no success.

Comment: that should be closer to success than Margins

Comment: ОК. I'll repeat with "grid in grid" technology and post a result.

Answer (score 1):

Layout via fixed Margins in not adaptive. There is nothing wrong in using nested Panels:

`UniformGrid` can arrange equal space for each child element (GroupBox).

```
<Grid ShowGridLines="True">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="80*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="512*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="160*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <UniformGrid Rows="1" Grid.Row="2">
        <GroupBox x:Name="groupBox_Copy" Header="Truck2" Height="148" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Button x:Name="button_Copy" Content="Start" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,13,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        </GroupBox>
        <GroupBox x:Name="groupBox_Copy1" Header="Truck3" Height="148" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Button x:Name="button_Copy1" Content="Start" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,13,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        </GroupBox>
        <GroupBox x:Name="groupBox_Copy2" Header="Truck1" Height="148" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Button x:Name="button" Content="Start" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,13,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        </GroupBox>
    </UniformGrid>

    <Image x:Name="image" Grid.Row="1" Source="Resources/truck.png"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

1024x768.
[image]

1920x1080.
Looks a little better. However, the controls "swam" to left direction. As can be seen.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="768" Width="1024"  MinHeight="768" MinWidth="1024" MaxHeight="1080" MaxWidth="1920">

<Grid  ShowGridLines="True">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="80*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="512*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="160*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Image x:Name="image"  Grid.Row="1"  Source="Resources/truck.png"/>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="138" Margin="10,9.6,0,0" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="998">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="125*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="143*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="147*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="143*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="171*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="143*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="120*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <GroupBox x:Name="GroupBox1" Grid.Column="1" Header="Truck1" Background="SeaShell" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0.4,0,147.6,0">
            <Button x:Name="button_Copy2" Content="Start" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="59,23,-2,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" RenderTransformOrigin="-1.211,-0.299"/>
        </GroupBox>
        <GroupBox x:Name="GroupBox2" Grid.Column="3" Header="Truck2" Background="SeaShell" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0.4,0,171.6,0">
            <Button x:Name="button_Copy" Content="Start" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="59,23,-2,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" RenderTransformOrigin="-1.211,-0.299"/>
        </GroupBox>
        <GroupBox x:Name="GroupBox3" Grid.Column="5" Header="Truck3" Background="SeaShell" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0.4,0,120.4,0">
            <Button x:Name="button_Copy1" Content="Start" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="59,23,-2,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        </GroupBox>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Margins, which designer adds after dropping controls from Toolbar - they mess entire layout. Adaptive layout in WPF is achieved mostly by using correct Panel (Grid, StackPanel, WrapPanel, UniformGrid, and rarely Canvas) - they arrange elements differently.

Comment: also correct Horizontal/Vertical Alignment are important. Remove `HorizontalAlignment="Left"`, and `Width="998"` from Grid and there will be notable improvement

Comment: Oh Godness, I've lost my last improvement. And currently have no clue what I did to get things better. :) Who did invent that WPF? There's no logic at all there...Only experiments...